# Unable to add values while merging two Maps

Tags: scala

```
val map1: Map[Int, Double] = ...
map1 ++ map2.map{ case (k,v: Double) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k,0)) }

[ERROR] ...<code location>...: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
[ERROR]   (x: Double)Double <and>
[ERROR]   (x: Float)Double <and>
[ERROR]   (x: Long)Double <and>
[ERROR]   (x: Int)Double <and>
[ERROR]   (x: Char)Double <and>
[ERROR]   (x: Short)Double <and>
[ERROR]   (x: Byte)Double <and>
[ERROR]   (x: String)String
[ERROR]  cannot be applied to (AnyVal)
[ERROR]         .map{ case (k, v: Double)  => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k, 0)) }
[ERROR]                                               ^
```

On the one side of that `+`, there is `v: Double`; on the other there is a getOrElse from a `Map[Int, Double]`. This addition has to be `Double + Double`. Where does this error come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say,

```
val map1 = Map(1->2.0,2->3.0,3->4.0,4->5.0,5->6.0)
val map2 = Map(1->2.5,3->1.0,4->3.2,7->3.0,6->1.23)
```

Now use

```
 map1 ++ map2.map{ case (k,v: Double) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k,0.0)) }
```

***instead of***

```
map1 ++ map2.map{ case (k,v: Double) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k,0)) }
```

Your substitution of `Int` `0` instead of a `Double` `0.0`. That is why the `type` returned by `getOrElse` method is being inferred as `AnyVal`. The operator `+` is not defined to be overloaded as `Double + AnyVal`. When both are `Double`'s it will be inferred correctly as expected as `+` is defined on `Double`s. `getOrElse` method returns a `value`(`Double`) associated with a particular `key` `k(Int)` supplied, if that particular `k` is not found it should  return an appropriate `Double` only ie., `0.0` in this case, otherwise it will return `AnyVal` or `Any` depending on what we supply an `Int` or `String` as second parameter of `getOrElse` function.

***In Scala REPL:***

```
scala> map1 ++ map2.map{ case (k,v: Double) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k,0.0)) }
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double] = Map(5 -> 6.0, 1 -> 4.5, 6 -> 1.23, 2 -> 3.0, 7 -> 3.0, 3 -> 5.0, 4 -> 8.2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem:

```
map1.getOrElse(k,0:Double) or map1.getOrElse(k,0d)
```

map1.getOrElse(k,0) will return a `Any` type as `0` is treated as Integer here:

```
scala> map1.getOrElse(1,0)
res11: AnyVal = 2.0
```

Comment: I think it is not `Any` but `AnyVal` .Though minor typo, but felt to mention in comment